# MATLAB: How to make a figure fit the screen on a 2nd monitor?

Tags: matlab, size, screen, fullscreen, matlab-figure

I exclusively use an external monitor connected to my laptop (laptop's screen is turned off). When I try to make a MATLAB figure fit the screen it only gets a size big enough to fit the laptop screen (which has a lower resolution) it seems. I use the following:

```
figure('outerposition',get(0,'screensize')); % or 'monitorpositions'
```

I even tried:

```
figure('outerposition',[0 0 1 1.2]);
```

but it does not do it and the figure only fits a part of the monitor's screen.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am out of ideas.

P.-S. What I would like to do, ultimately, is to have a figure fit 90% (for example) of the screen (width and height).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you get when you type: `get(0,'MonitorPositions')`? Take a look at my answer below to see what may cause the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be related to [this note in the documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/root-properties.html#property_d0e876808):

> MATLAB sets the display information values for this property at startup. The values are static. If your system display settings change, the values do not update. To refresh the values, restart MATLAB.

In my desktop, starting Matlab with only one active screen gives that:

```
>> get(0,'MonitorPositions')
ans =
           1           1        1280        1024
```

and even if I try to activate the screen later, **it doesn't change**. However, if I activate the second screen and then restart Matlab, I get:

```
>> get(0,'MonitorPositions')
ans =
       -1919        -123        1920        1080
           1           1        1280        1024
```

And then I can set the figure to this size:

```
figure('OuterPosition',[-1920 -123 3200 1080]);
```

which covers both screens.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @EBH. Your comment is relevant to the question but I did not change my display settings at any point. Always used only the external monitor. The problem is, even if I use 'Normalized' units and put '[0 0 1 1]' for 'OuterPosition', it does not fill the whole screen for some reason. Surprisingly, after trying many things, rebooting the PC did the job! Now, simply having 'OuterPosition' to '[0 0 1 1]' fills the screen. But this unfortunately does not give an answer to why did the problem appear.

Comment: @Jin, I am surprised you didn't try to reboot before you asked ;)

Comment: I tried restarting MATLAB, but rebooting the PC didn't come to my mind as there is no logical explanation I could come with to why it would solve the problem (even though it often does miracles I must admit).

Answer (score 1):

This solution is based on the `screensize` function written by Doug Schwarz in [this Newsreader thread](https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/171606).

I have done some quick tests, it seems to return the desired results, find my adaptation at the bottom of this post.

#### Example use

Fullscreen, monitor 2

```
% Pass the monitor number to the screensize function, this example uses monitor 2
sz = screensize(2); 
% The function returns pixel values, so must use units pixels
% Set the outerposition according to that.
figure('units', 'pixels', 'outerposition', sz)
```

Just filling 90% of the screen, monitor 2:

```
sz = screensize(2);
pad = 0.05; % 5% padding all around
szpadded = [sz(1:2) + sz(3:4)*pad, sz(3:4)*(1-2*pad)];
figure('units', 'pixels', 'outerposition', szpadded);
```

#### `screensize` function

Doug's original code relied on moving the mouse pointer to get positions, I'm not sure why and have slimmed that code down. I've also removed code duplication etc. to make things a bit more compact. The function essentially relies on getting the screen device array from the java back end.

```
function ss_out = screensize(screen_number)
%screensize: return screen coordinates of multiple monitors.
    % Version: 1.0, 26 June 2008 Author: Douglas M. Schwarz
    % Version: 1.1, 21 July 2017 Author: Wolfie 
    persistent myss
    if isempty(myss)
        % Get Screen Devices array.
        sd = java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment.getScreenDevices;
        % Initialize screensize array.
        num_screens = length(sd);
        myss = zeros(num_screens,4);
        % Loop over all Screen Devices.
        for ii = 1:num_screens
            bounds = sd(ii).getDefaultConfiguration.getBounds;
            myss(ii,:) = [bounds.x, bounds.y, bounds.width, bounds.height];
        end
    end
    num_screens = size(myss,1);
    if nargin == 0
        screen_number = 1:num_screens;
    end
    screen_index = min(screen_number,num_screens);
    ss_out = myss(screen_index,:);
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Wolfie. After trying many things and your solution, I ended rebooting my PC, which surprisingly solved the problem. I know have 'OuterPosition' to [0 0 1 1] (with 'Normalized' units) to fill the screen and [.05 .05 .90 .90] to fill only 90% of it, which is working. I have no idea why was the initial problem so persistent though and why it did appear.